# Прилагательные, образованные от существительных

Tags: части-речи

Какие прилагательные можно образовать от слов "метро", "ландыш", "речка"?

Answer (score 1):

Ландышевый, речной.

Answer (score 0):

От слова "речка" прилагательное не образуется, поскольку "речка" тоже образовалось от слова "река. Поэтому, как уже было сказано выше, "речной". Насчет "ландыша" соглашусь, а что до "метро", то тут опять же имеет место сокращение от слова "метрополитен", поэтому, думаю, будет "метрополитенный".

Answer (score 0):

Не метрополитенный, а метрополитеновский.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%EC%E5%F2%F0%EE%EF%2A%E9

Answer (score 0):

Разбор  слова как часть речи:к метро сущ. (что?).Н.ф -метро.Неодуш.,нариц.,ср.р.,в Д.п.,в еч.ч.Втор.чл.

Comment: Это правильно у меня учитель проверил!